# Theorem numbering over chapter

Tags: amsthm

I have a problem with theorem numbering. If anyone has solutions, please help me.

My document has two chapters. In 2nd chapter, one theorem is written and numbering like Theorem 2.1.1. Now I want to state the same theorem with the same number in chapter 1 like I want Theorem 2.1.1 in chapter 1. Please, if anyone has solutions or suggestions, let me know.

I am using the following packages and running the file in LaTeX+DviPs+PDF Viewer+Ps2Pdf setting

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[]{cite}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{notoccite}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{pst-grad} % For gradients
\usepackage{pst-plot} % For axes
\usepackage[space]{grffile} % For spaces in paths
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{threeparttable,placeins,caption,stfloats}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{mathtools,relsize}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{subfigure,makecell,stfloats}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{symb}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[symb,1
{label=,labelwidth=1in,align=parleft,itemsep=0.1\baselineskip,leftmargin=!}
```

Comment: What does the "state" mean? Mention only the number or name of Theorem 2.1.1 in chapter 1, or restate the whole contents of Theorem 2.1.1?

Comment: "state" indicates that I want to write the same theorem in chapter 1 with the same theorem number.

Comment: No..it is not working.

Comment: Can you post a complete example showing what is not working? Maybe it is other setting codes in you document that are not compatible `thmtools` used in the answer to linked question.

Comment: I had updated the question with using packages and compile setting.

Comment: Please give a _complete example_ (also called [mwe]((https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228))) that others can compile after copy-and-paste. You can use comments to indicate where you want to restate Theorem 2.1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on OP's preamble, the following full example works.

I comment pacakge `tkz-graph` since

> This package has been taken temporarily out of circulation to give the author time to investigate some problems.
>
> from https://ctan.org/pkg/tkz-graph

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[]{cite}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{notoccite}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{pst-grad} % For gradients
\usepackage{pst-plot} % For axes
\usepackage[space]{grffile} % For spaces in paths
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{threeparttable,placeins,caption,stfloats}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{mathtools,relsize}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{subfigure,makecell,stfloats}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{symb}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[symb,1]
{label=,labelwidth=1in,align=parleft,itemsep=0.1\baselineskip,leftmargin=!}

\usepackage{thm-restate}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}
\chapter{title}
\section{title}
\begin{restatable*}[Goldbach's conjecture]{thm}{goldbach}
\label{thm:goldbach}
Every even integer greater than 2 can be expressed as the sum of two primes.
\end{restatable*}

\chapter{title}
\section{title}
\goldbach
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you. It is working fine.